# Make a WCF .NET service implementation implement multiple ServiceContract interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, exception

I am developing a RESTful webservice using WCF. I would like to have a `ServiceContract` interface that all my services implement, however, I would also like each service to aditionally implement their own methods.

In my Global.asax file I initialize the service routes:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("iOSAppService", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Service.iOSAppService)));
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("AndroidAppService", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Service.AndroidAppService)));
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("WindowsPhoneAppService", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Service.WindowsPhoneAppService)));
```

Each of the services must implement the `IAppService` interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAppService
```

Which is implemented as follows:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class iOSAppService : IAppService
```

However, I would for instance also like the `iOSAppService` to implement the IiOSApService interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IiOSAppService
```

Thus resulting in the implementation:

```
public class iOSAppService : IAppService, IiOSAppService
```

However, this results in the following exception:

> *Service 'iOSAppService' implements multiple ServiceContract types, and no endpoints are defined in the configuration file. WebServiceHost can set up default endpoints, but only if the service implements only a single ServiceContract. Either change the service to only implement a single ServiceContract, or else define endpoints for the service explicitly in the configuration file.*

Does anyone know how I can achieve my goal?

Comment: A DataContract defines what data gets serialized. A ServiceContract exposes the methods. I don't think you want your ServiceContract inheriting your DataContract. As the error says, they are two different types of contracts.

Comment: Why do you decorate an interface with `[DataContract]`? This attribute for classes which are participate as arguments (in- or -return types). `ServiceContract` and `OperationContract` attributes are for services and their methods.

Comment: @abatishchev Based on the error message, I think that's a typo. Based on the question, I'm pretty sure the OP knows the difference between a DataContract and a ServiceContract.

Comment: @shambulator That's right it was just a typo.

Comment: @Zappel How much do you know about working with WCF configuration? The basic problem is that you can't rely on the default config-less setup, and will have to define your endpoints in config the way you had to do before .NET 4.0. I just haven't had time to write up a full answer for you.

Comment: @shambulator Again, you are right. I do not have any experience working with WCF prior to .NET 4.0 and would hence be very pleased to know what the approach to solve the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your specyfic interface like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IiOSAppService : IAppService
```

And then

```
public class iOSAppService : IiOSAppService
```

**Edit:**

On service side make sure you have:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="YourNamespace.iOSAppService">
      <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="YourNamespace.IiOSAppService" behaviorConfiguration="web">
      </endpoint>
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="web">
        <webHttp />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am presented with the exact same error by doing this.